# Other Volumes in Container taking up 2/3 of hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, storage, apfs

My Macbook Pro is completely full and after hours of searching for what files might cause this I came across the "Other Volumes in Container" category that's taking up a massive amount of my drive (162.75GB of the 256GB hard drive).

This computer was originally my dad's. I wiped the computer clean and configured it from scratch (didn't restore from an iCloud backup). Could this be leftover from his old files in some way?

How can I clean this out? What is included in this? It's crazy because I really don't have that much on this computer.

2017 MacBook Pro 13" currently on Big Sur trying to upgrade to Monterey but not enough storage space.

[image: Screenshot of Other Volumes in Container]

Comment: "Other Volumes In Container" is "Macintosh HD - Data", among others.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out..

Apparently when I wiped the computer to start from scratch for some reason it kept all 150gb of my dad's files on it. I simply erased the disk that had the 150gb on it in the Disk Utility and I now have a glorious amount of space remaining.

Answer (score 0):

So, just for your knowledge - the way that APFS (Apple File System, how your drive is likely formatted) is that it is considered a 'container' of other drive partitions - or as they're called, volumes.

The way that I generally wipe a Mac (and how I would recommend you do so in future) is to completely delete the container in Disk Utility of the installer application which I burn to a USB. Create the container again, your drive will be completely clean.